# checking an email uniqueness before submitting a sign up form

Tags: javascript, form-submit, email-validation

I've got trouble with checking an email uniqueness in the client side before submitting a sign up form to the server side.

```
submitButton.onclick = function(){
    var email = $('input[name = "email"]').val();
    var checkEmail;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'serverScripts/settings/checkEmailAvailability.php',
        data: {email: email},
        async: false,
        success: function(text){
            checkEmail = text;//Return "occupied" or "freeToUse"
        }
    });
    if(checkEmail == 'occupied'){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your trouble? i.e, what's not working

Comment: What is the exact issue? It's not working or your javascript is giving a error?

Comment: Synchronous XHR gives a terrible user experience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to do that script correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:alert('it went though pipes')" method="get">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">
</form>
<script>
$('form').submit(function(){
    var email = $('input[name = "email"]').val();
    var checkEmail = $.ajax({
        url: 'serverScripts/settings/checkEmailAvailability.php',
        data: {email: email},
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
    if(result.search('occupied')!=-1){
        alert("You've done something WRONG");
        return false;
    }
})
</script>
```

Now maybe some explanation. It uses jQuery. The `<form action="...">` is just for fun, replace it will real address and feel free to insert `<form>` into real page. Now what was wrong? `text` is reserved in JS, you cannot use it, so I changed it to `data`. Also, I decided to use .search while searching for "occupied" and change the method which you use onsubmit a little :P.

I made quick testing page, if you're interested: (the only accepted is pass@me.com if you want to know).

http://glitchmr.pl/nuda/test.html

(also, `$.ajax` is specific to jQuery, if you don't use it already)

Comment: Internal Server Errors have nothing to this code. It's error which happened during processing the script by such tool as PHP. The issue is probably your PHP script. Can you paste it or something?

Comment: Can you try to apply a different action in form. Like signUp.php ?

Comment: Of course. The `<form action="...">` is just for fun, replace it will real address and feel free to insert `<form>` into real page. In other words, you can type there `parse.php` or anything like this. I used `javascript:` to check if everything is ok, without actually passing it to server.

Comment: Ok found what the problem was. I had a header(Location: something) which was causing the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Your script at : serverScripts/settings/checkEmailAvailability.php

is expecting a variable called "email"

your php script then should query the db and test if its available or not and return "occupied" if it's in the db .

else it's a valid email address to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is your naming of the variables. See this section:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'serverScripts/settings/checkEmailAvailability.php',
    data: {email: email},
    async: false,
    success: function(text){
        checkEmail = text;//Return "occupied" or "freeToUse"
    }
});
```

It probably should be

```
data: {'email': email},
```

notice the quotes. As it stands, you are creating a data element of

```
{joe.blow@email.com, joe.blow@email.com}
```

while it should be

```
{email: joe.blow@email.com}
```

Comment: Wrong! It should be checking in the client side

Comment: What does that even mean? A bit more info would really help here.